# Solr Installation error : NativeCommandError

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework, powershell

I am setting up the Solr 6.6.2 with SSL for Sitecore 9 installation on one of the new development machine.

I am following the Kam Figy PS script :

https://gist.github.com/kamsar/c3c8322c1ec40eac64c7dd546e5124de

But I am getting the below error while I am executing the solrssl.PS1 script:

```
PS G:\Sitecore9\SSL> .\solrssl.ps1 -KeyStoreFile C:\solr-6.6.2\server\etc\solr-ssl.keystore.jks -Clobber
Removing C:\solr-6.6.2\server\etc\solr-ssl.keystore.jks...

Generating JKS keystore...
C:\solr-6.6.2\server\etc\solr-ssl.keystore.p12

Generating .p12 to import to Windows...
keytool.exe : Importing keystore C:\solr-6.6.2\server\etc\solr-ssl.keystore.jks to 
C:\solr-6.6.2\server\etc\solr-ssl.keystore.p12...
At G:\Sitecore9\SSL\solrssl.ps1:54 char:1
+ & $keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $KeystoreFile -destkeystore $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Importing keyst...keystore.p12...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I have already set the environment variable of JRE and changed the Keytool path as below :

```
$keytool = (Get-Command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\bin\keytool.exe').Source
```

I am using JRE version 10.0.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alternate script by jermdavis, which works like a charm. I forked it, though, because it had one issue.

https://gist.github.com/isaadansari/bd5949c77a6c1dbb80ec2d12d1d9f731

You can manually download the, solr version package 6.6.2 and nssm version 2.24
and place them in your desired folder after extracting, Lets suppose:

`c:\solr\solr-6.6.2`

`c:\solr\nssm-2.24`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but JRE version 10.0.1 might be having some compatibility issues with Solr 6.6.2 , I had used Java Version 8 and it worked for me.

Please check the following post on this problem.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-9-installation-errors-solutions-pratik-wasnik